# How to remove pending action

Tags: notepad++

Every time I start NotePad++ there's a popup saying:

> There are still some pending actions to complete installing or
>   removing some plugins

I was trying to install Plugin Manager, but I couldn't due to lack of admin right.
How can I get rid of this annoying notification?

Comment: Finish installing Plugin Manager would be the simplest way.

Comment: Can you edit xml files under %APPDATA%\Notepad++ ?

Comment: @Ramhound I can't finish installing because I'm not system administrator

Comment: @malakrsnaslava Yes, I can edit these XMLs

Comment: You can't get an `Administrator` to install it for you?  Any solution I myself would do would require your `Administrator` to help you.

Comment: Solved. I manually removed "plugin_install_temp" directory from %APPDATA%\Notepad++

@malakrsnaslava Thanks for clue.

Comment: Try using Portable version [http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable] of **notepad++** so that you can install without Administrator rights.

Comment: @Wishwas problem exists in portable too, solution is to delete ...\Notepad++Portable\Data\Config\plugins\config\PluginManagerGpup.xml

Answer (score 75):

To 'reset' the plugin updates, you need to delete the below file.

> %APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\Config\PluginManagerGpup.xml

Deleting this file will also result in the cleanup of the "plugin_install_temp" directory upon the next startup of the application.

Source:
https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/blob/master/pluginManager/src/PluginManager.cpp#L341

Comment: In my case the xml-File was not in AppData but in the installDir of NPP. But the solution worked nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you. With Notepad++ Portable, I've found this file in `...\Notepad++Portable\Data\Config\plugins\config`

Comment: This answer gives the wrong path to the plugins folder if Notepad++ was not installed to the default location. A better, more general, answer is the one given by `Wikis`.

Answer (score 17):

The other answers did not work for me because those files did not exist. Nor could I find them in another location using Windows-7 search.

However, they did exist. I found their location via Notepad++. In the menu select:

> Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager

then in the pop up press

> Settings

At the bottom of *this* dialog is a section marked **Information**. This will start:

> Plugin Config path is:

Open this location in Windows Explorer. You will need to delete files from this location. But before you then delete these files, **close Notepad++**. (I have seen some files recreated if Notepad++ was left open.)

Then delete these files:

- PluginManager.ini
- PluginManagerPlugins.xml
- PluginManagerPlugins.zip

and the folder

- plugin_install_temp

Then start Notepad++ again. Here you may see the **Notepad ++ Plugin Manager** dialog. Ensure that any plugins are checked and press

> Ignore Selected Updates

Finally, return to the Plugin Manager:

> Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager

Press

> Settings

and uncheck:

> Notify of plugin updates at startup

*Probably some of these steps (eg deleting **all** these files) are redundant but this worked for me.*

Comment: This is a good answer, but gives too much (and inaccurate) information. Firstly, the `plugin_install_temp`, folder does NOT need to be deleted. It will be deleted automatically on the next start of Notepad++. Secondly, the bit about ignoring selected updates was NOT asked by the OP and should be marked eg. "Do the following if you wish to ignore updates in future" or left out. It should not included as part of the answer.

Comment: It is worth noticing that for me issue has gone only when I deleted also `PluginManagerGpup.xml` - see https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11243/how-to-cancel-a-pending-plugin-installation

Comment: Adding to what eadel says, all the wikis steps plus the gpup file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I manually removed "plugin_install_temp" directory from %APPDATA%\Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by re-installing plugin manager (check Plugin Manager under Installed tab and choose reinstall)

Comment: This is what cases it for me in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Delete PluginManagerGpup.xml from ...\%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\config and/or your local ...\Notepad++\plugins\config directories.

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11243/how-to-cancel-a-pending-plugin-installation